# passing cookie to my webbrowser

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I m trying to develop an app for WP7 in Visual Studio 2010 in C#. I have a specific use case. I want to upload some photos to a website which hosts photos. First I launch the webbrowser to authenticate once I get authenticated I select a particular picture and upload it. after that I m trying to launch the browser it should automatically login with the credentials passed earlier. I have tried some methods but did not work. So here is my requirement

1) I want to store the login credentials entered to my web browser using a cookie or a file.

2) I want to pass the same credentials to the webbrowser when its launched again after sometime.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just keep your browser open?
You can get the cookies using the [GetCookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowserext.getcookies%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) method, but it doesn't seem to be a way of setting them back.

Comment: is there any way to read the login credentials which the user has given from the cookies ??? Please provide me some sample code

Comment: Most sites store just a token in the cookies, not the credentials. You should try keeping the browser open. Also, maybe this site you're using has public web services that you can use instead of a web browser.